# Calculating the expected value when random variables are not numbers

Tags: probability, expected-value

in one of our courses we were given the following:

[image]

We are asked to calculate $$E_{P(H)}[E[Y|T=1,H]]-E[Y|T=0,H]]$$. Since we also have to calculate the expected value of Y conditioned over handedness, I am not really sure how to take into account the handedness when numerically evaluating the expectation. Do I assign a 0 to R, and a 1 to L?

Comment: what do Y(0) and Y(1) correspond to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Handedness is just a set you're conditioning on. The only variable that needs to be numeric is $Y$ in your case as you have to calculate the expectation over it.

\begin{align*}
E_{H}[E[Y|T=1,H]-E[Y|T=0,H]] &= \left(E[Y|T=1,H=left]-E[Y|T=0,H=left]\right)\mathbb P(H=left) +\\&\qquad \left(E[Y|T=1,H=right]-E[Y|T=0,H=right]\right)\mathbb P(H=right)\\
&= \left(\frac{60+75+53+69}{4}-63\right)\frac{5}{10} +\left(50-\frac{42+50+58+59}{4}\right)\frac{5}{10}\\
&= (64.25-63)*0.5+(50-52.25)*0.5\\
&= -\frac{1}{2}
\end{align*}